# Dropbox API v2 (and v1) "list" folder with recursive=true is missing Shared folders

Tags: java, recursion, dropbox-api

What I did:
Using dropbox-sdk-2-1-1 for java.

Api url:
https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder

List folders in a dropbox folder. Set recursive to false.

All subFolders are returned, including shared folders.

However, if I set recursive to true.
All subFolders with recursive subFolders are returned, except from shared folders.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.

https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206081056--SwiftyDropbox-client-files-listFolder-recursive-true-doesn-t-list-shared-folders

The problem is that shared folders always are returned on the next page, even though the result data is small. Using "hasMore" and "cursor" to get the rest of the result solved the issue.

Comment: Does this look better?